# Как распределить расширения

Tags: c#

```
string text = ".data.file.crypt";
```

Как можно преобразовать данный текст для паттернов расширение через поиск

```
foreach (var list in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", тут паттерн, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
{
   Console.WriteLine(list);
}
```

Так же сделать что если вдруг в `string text = ".data .file .crypt";` есть пробелы, переход на новую строку, то убрать их и сделать всё в одну строку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File globbing in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing;

string text = ".data .file.crypt";

var patterns = text.Split(new[] { ' ', '.', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => "*." + x);

Matcher matcher = new();
matcher.AddIncludePatterns(patterns);

foreach (var file in matcher.GetResultsInFullPath("."))
    Console.WriteLine(file);
```

Comment: А без Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing имеется возможность сделать?

Comment: @AndreyVasiliykov - https://stackoverflow.com/q/163162/5045688